# javascript Calculating moment subtraction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, momentjs

I want to subtract the ones formatted by one and two respectively.
ones and twos are json values ​​and moment was applied.
But in substract , an error occurs saying there is no string in substract.

```
const one = ones.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"); // 2023-01-18 22:01:42
const two = twos.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"); // 2023-01-16 05:01:21
const result = one.subtract(two);
```

I want to subtract one and two values ​​from each other and put them into a variable. How should I handle it?

Comment: what is `ones` and `twos`? What error do you get?

Comment: it's spelled "subtract", not "substract"

Comment: @Jamiec ones and twos are json values ​​and moment was applied.

Comment: right so call `subtract` on the moment values, not the strings!

Comment: You can't subtract formatted date, because formatted date is just a string of text. First subtract, then format